# hbase not starting

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase

I am Trying to get a connection in hbase from java client api.

This is my code. Here i have written some code to get connection in hbase.

I am not getting any error when i run this code. But i cant create any table with this.

```
Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    try {

        hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.rootdir",
                "file:///home/sample/hbase");
        hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir",
                "/home/sample/zookeeper");
        hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
                "sample");
        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(hbaseConfiguration);
        HConnection connection = HConnectionManager
                .getConnection(newConfig);
        hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(connection);
        hBaseAdmin.createTable(new HTableDescriptor("sample"));
        if (!hBaseAdmin.isMasterRunning())
            throw new Exception("Hbase is not running");
        tableFactory = new HTableFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Hbase is not running");
    }
```

Can anyone help me out for this?? Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Change following code

```
    hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.rootdir",
            "file:///home/sample/hbase");
    hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir",
            "/home/sample/zookeeper");
    hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
            "sample");
```

to

```
hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
            "rs1.example.com");
```

Note: `rs1.example.com` should be replaced with an address point to your zookeeper cluster. You can find the value in your `conf/hbase-site.xml`.

Comment: thanks for your comment... but i cant get you.. where should i change that rs1.example.com. i have changed hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "rs1.example.com");

Comment: Have you setup a running HBase instance?

Answer (score 0):

The `hbase.rootdir` setting will be completely ignored. It can only be set in the *hbase-site.xml* file.